# How to disable certain links in React native webview

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I am using the react-native-webview in my react native app for the blog posts. My Code is pretty simple, though i need to limit the webview to only limit to the blog section of the website and not be able to traverse the website.

```html
const BlogScreen = () => {
  const runFirst = `
  document.querySelector(".mobile-bottom-nav-menu").style.display = "none";
  document.querySelector(".header, .js-sticky-header, .fixed-top").style.display = "none";
      true`;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://www.****.com',
          }}
          onMessage={(event) => {}}
          injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default BlogScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

We cant disable link but, In webView you can manage any change in navigation from prop onNavigationStateChange, so when a user tries to change any navigation you can handle with this prop.

**Answer Source link** : https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange